# Where can I find a knife blade with no handle?

Tags: tools, woodworking

I would like to make a nice wooden handle for a knife, but I do not have the means of cutting out a blade shape from scratch.

Where are some places I could look, or some search terms for a knife blade without a handle?  I am not asking for people to shop for me - that is against the rules - I am, however, looking for some search terms or formal names for this type of item.

It doesn't make a difference if the blade is sharp or not because I am going to resharpen it once I make and mount a handle.

Comment: This would have made more sense to ask in the chat room. It looks like a shopping question that you're trying to rephrase as something else.

Comment: I agree, shopping question, but since it's here, look at Lee Valley (I'm just a customer) http://www.leevalley.com/en/wood/page.aspx?p=31078&cat=1,130,43332,43393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for "[knife blade blanks](https://www.google.com/search?q=knife%20blade%20blanks&oq=knife%20blade%20blanks)" which seems to turn up quite a few full tang blandes without scales.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I don't know how it is off topic!

Answer (score 1):

Some people have been known to grind a knife blade using a file as a starting place. The file is a hard steel item that if ground without over heating could lead to a nice knife blade.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to a used tool store/salvation army/junk store, and buy a knife you like the blade of. Remove the handle and have fun regrinding the blade.

Cheap and easy!